# How to get list of your own (registered) Azure images?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

If I do `az vm image list`, I get list aff public images,
but not my images.

```
$ az vm image list --output table                                                                                                                                                                                            You are viewing an offline list of images, use --all to retrieve an up-to-date list
Offer          Publisher               Sku                 Urn                                                             UrnAlias             Version
-------------  ----------------------  ------------------  --------------------------------------------------------------  -------------------  ---------
WindowsServer  MicrosoftWindowsServer  2016-Datacenter     MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2016-Datacenter:latest     Win2016Datacenter    latest
WindowsServer  MicrosoftWindowsServer  2012-R2-Datacenter  MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2012-R2-Datacenter:latest  Win2012R2Datacenter  latest
WindowsServer  MicrosoftWindowsServer  2008-R2-SP1         MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2008-R2-SP1:latest         Win2008R2SP1         latest
WindowsServer  MicrosoftWindowsServer  2012-Datacenter     MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2012-Datacenter:latest     Win2012Datacenter    latest
UbuntuServer   Canonical               16.04-LTS           Canonical:UbuntuServer:16.04-LTS:latest                         UbuntuLTS            latest
CentOS         OpenLogic               7.3                 OpenLogic:CentOS:7.3:latest                                     CentOS               latest
openSUSE-Leap  SUSE                    42.2                SUSE:openSUSE-Leap:42.2:latest                                  openSUSE-Leap        latest
RHEL           RedHat                  7.3                 RedHat:RHEL:7.3:latest                                          RHEL                 latest
SLES           SUSE                    12-SP2              SUSE:SLES:12-SP2:latest                                         SLES                 latest
Debian         credativ                8                   credativ:Debian:8:latest                                        Debian               latest
CoreOS         CoreOS                  Stable              CoreOS:CoreOS:Stable:latest                                     CoreOS               latest
```

How do I get list of my images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Images under your subscription, use **az image list [--resource-group]**

Refer [az image list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/image?view=azure-cli-latest#az_image_list) for more details.